AWS Cognito Pre Auth Trigger Error" Unrecognizable lambda output"
I'm trying to suppress the aws.cognito.signin.user.admin scope from being in the access token in certain cases. I am getting the following error
Error authenticating with Cognito: InvalidLambdaResponseException: Unrecognizable lambda output
This is the output of my lambda function with placeholder values for user and pool info
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "us-east-2",
    "userPoolId": "userpool",
    "userName": "id",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-nodejs-2.1584.0",
        "clientId": "clientid"
    },
    "triggerSource": "PreAuthentication_Authentication",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "sub": "10aa03fc-d238-45ca-ab7d-6a86942b76c2",
            "cognito:email_alias": "blah@gmail.com",
            "cognito:user_status": "CONFIRMED",
            "email_verified": "true",
            "name": "Blah",
            "email": "blah@gmail.com"
        },
        "validationData": null,
        "userNotFound": false
    },
    "response": {
        "claimsAndScopeOverrideDetails": {
            "accessTokenGeneration": {
                "scopesToAdd": [
                    "openid"
                ],
                "scopesToSuppress": [
                    "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}


Here is my code
export const handler = function(event: any, context: any) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event));

    // Retrieve user attributes from the event request
    const userAttributes = event.request.userAttributes;

    // Construct the response based on the example structure
    event.response = {
        "claimsAndScopeOverrideDetails": {
            "accessTokenGeneration": {
                "claimsToAddOrOverride": {},
                "scopesToAdd": userAttributes['cognito:email_alias'] === 'blah@gmail.com' ? ['openid'] : [],
                "scopesToSuppress": userAttributes['cognito:email_alias'] === 'blah@gmail.com' ? ['aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'] : []
            },
            "groupOverrideDetails": {}
        }
    };

    // Log the constructed response for debugging
    console.log('Response:', JSON.stringify(event.response));

    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    context.done(null, event);
};



Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Nvm, I figured it out. By default, Cognito delivers version 1 of the events. The scopesToSuppress and scopesToAdd aren't available until version 2 of the events. To turn this version on, you have to enable advanced security features which in turn is expensive for just this use case.
